# Pivot table columns into rows with Primary Key Foreign Key relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

**Table1**:

```
  Columns     PK_Table1   Name | DoYouGoToSchool |DoYouhaveACar |DoYouWorkFullTime | DoYouWorkPartTime  |  Score
                1          joe     Yes               Yes              No                   Yes   
                2          amy     No                Yes              Yes                  No
```

How do I pivot this and insert into a new Table2 with its unique Id (PK_table1 mapped to FK_Table1)

Expected result in Table 2, what I am looking for is **FK_Tablel1** maintaining its relationship with Table1

[image]

As you can see the result follows the Pivoted Columns into rows and maintains the PK-FK relationship inserting FK's to the table.

Here is the query I was playing with:

```
create table #Table1
(
    PK_Table1         int IDENTITY, 
    Name              Varchar(50), 
    DoYouGoToSchool   Varchar(8),
    DoYouhaveACar     Varchar(8),
    DoYouWorkFullTime Varchar(8),
    DoYouWorkPartTime Varchar(8),
    Score             int null,
)

create table #Table2
(
    PK_Table2 int IDENTITY,
    FK_Table1 int null,
    Questions Varchar(50),   
    Answer    Varchar(8)
)

INSERT INTO #Table1 (Name, DoYouGoToSchool, DoYouhaveACar, DoYouWorkFullTime, DoYouWorkPartTime)
VALUES ('joe', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No', 'Yes'), 
       ('amy', 'NO', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can use UnPivot Also

```
INSERT INTO #Table2 (FK_Table1, Questions, Answer)

 SELECT  PK_Table1 AS FK_Table1
        ,Questions
        ,Answers 
 FROM #Table1 t
 UNPIVOT
 (
 Answers FOR Questions IN ([DoYouGoToSchool],[DoYouhaveACar],[DoYouWorkFullTime],[DoYouWorkPartTime])
 ) AS unpvt
 WHERE PK_Table1<3
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `insert` statement with `apply` operator:

```
insert into #Table2 (FK_Table1, Questions, Answer)
select t.PK_Table1, t1.cols, colsval
from #Table1 t cross apply 
        (values ('DoYouGoToSchool', DoYouGoToSchool), 
                ('DoYouhaveACar', DoYouhaveACar), 
                ('DoYouWorkFullTime', DoYouWorkFullTime), 
                ('DoYouWorkPartTime', DoYouWorkPartTime)
        ) t1 (cols, colsval);
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: I know your answer is correct sorry but do you know how to get the answer column populated with its respective value i have added the screenshot .

Comment: I can do a seperate Update to that column but i was wondering if i can do in a single query. Thank you

Comment: @user3920526. . . Check Now.

Comment: Thank you for this.